# How to print the first letter from all elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

First of all, I want to save a user input into a variable called "name". Then, I want to print the last word of the name as it is, but for all other words of the name, I want to print only the first letter of the world in an uppercase letter. 
Suppose, name = "Stack Over Flow"
I want to make it S. O. Flow.

First of all, I split the name variable to separate the parts. I created a variable call lname with the last part of the name. Then again, I created a variable called fname with  all other words except the last word. 
I have tried for loop to print all first letters from fname. But, I can't assign them to a variable so that I can join them with the last part to make a full name.

```py
name=input()
name=name.split(' ')
lname = name[-1]
fname= name[:-1]
for z in fname:
    print(z[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are perhaps more pythonic ways to do this, but for the smallest code change, all you'd need to do is to add to a string and print it after looping. So, instead of printing `z[0]` you would add it to a string which would need to be instantiated prior to the loop. Then you could add the last-name to it before finally printing the entire string. i.e.

```
name=input()
name=name.split(' ')
lname = name[-1]
fname= name[:-1]
result = ""
for z in fname:
    result = result + z[0] + ". "
result = result + lname
print(result)
```

I would instead do the following:

```
name=input()
name=name.split(' ')
print('. '.join([n[0] if i != len(name) - 1 else n for i, n in enumerate(name)]))
```

which given `Stack Over Flow` returns `S. O. Flow`

This does not capitalize the letters for you, so if provided `stack over flow` it would return `s. o. flow`.

To break down the code I provided, the `'. '.join(<list>)` takes a list of strings and concatenates them together using the string `'. '`. This means that the code inside the join is providing the `['s', 'o', 'flow']`.

The code inside the join is called a list comprehension. It's effectively a flattened for loop which appends each result of the for loop to a list. [Section 5.1.3 of the python tutorial covers list comprehensions.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

That list comprehension takes the first letter of the name unless the index (i) of that string is equal to the last index of the list. This means with the input `Stack Over Flow` the len() is 3. The last index is 2 (counting from 0 --> 0=='Stack', 1=='Over', 2=='Flow'). Once the index == 2, it takes the entire name instead of the first letter.

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you both its index in the list and the element of the list which is why my `for` loop is `for i, n` instead of just `for n`.

The advantage of not hard-coding a value such as saying `== 2`, is for other inputs. What if a person does not have a middle name? E.g. `John Doe` should be `J. Doe`. With a hard-coded value of 2, the result would be `J. D.` instead. Or what if the input was for Mary Sue Elizabeth Smith? Her result should be M. S. E. Smith, but would not result in that output if the number of names is hard-coded in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

This answer takes advantage of advanced tuple unpacking (Python3) and f-strings (Python3.6)

```
name = "Stack Over Flow"

*first_words, last_word = name.split(" ")
first_letters = ' '.join([f"{w[0].upper()}." for w in first_words])

res = f"{first_letters} {last_word}"

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "Stack Over Flow"

words = name.split(" ")
first_words = words[:-1]
last_word = words[-1]

first_letters = [x[0] + "." for x in first_words]

res = "{} {}".format(" ".join(first_letters), last_word)
print(res)
```

will yield `S. O. Flow`

Comment: @Uchchash TR please mark the answer if it helped you

Comment: res = "{} {}".format(" ".join(first_letters), last_word) , can u kindly explain this line?

Comment: @UchchashTR what do you mean?

Comment: what are the uses of {}{} ?

Comment: @UchchashTR to combine the `S. O.` and `Flow`

Comment: @andreihondrari: I really think you should replace `words[:len(words) - 1]` with the *much* more pythonic `words[:-1]` (and similarly, `words[len(words) - 1]` with `words[-1]`)

Answer (score 1):

Yoi can use [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
name = "Stack Over Flow"
'.'.join([x[0] if i < 2 else x  for i, x in  enumerate(name.split())])
```

**Output:**

> S.O.Flow

References:

1. [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
2. [Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
3. [Join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)